# Always show more-events-popover with eventLimit 0

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need a functionality to limit events to 0, unfortunately there is no such option there can be only "+2 more" i know there is open issue for this:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2978

Maybe someone know how to solve this and can help me.

Comment: I think you'd probably have to modify the internals of fullCalendar to detect this. Probably too broad for this forum. If you really need it, you could try to make a fix, and contribute it to fullCalendar via GitHub, rather than waiting for someone else to do it. That's the beauty of open-source. If you get stuck with your fix, you could always post the code here and get some help on the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for respond i'm still trying but with no success, thats why im looking for some clues.

Comment: in that case, I'll repeat, post what you've done so far and maybe you can get some help with it. Asking for generic help to solve a problem is generally considered too broad and off-topic.

Comment: The first idea is to create hidden events to force fullcalendar render "1 more" link but this can create memory leaks and cause many other problems, however it works but i dont like this solution. Second idea is to edit source code but for now i didnt reach any progress soo there is nothing to share.

Comment: "to force fullcalendar render "1 more" link but this can create memory leaks". Really? It'd be interesting to see how you've done this because I can't immediately think of any reason why that should happen.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle to simulate this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/avn0ce51/

Comment: not sure what the link is demonstrating? I can see that you're inserting a hidden event into each day, but beyond that, what does it achieve? You talked about forcing it to render a "1 more" link, and about memory leaks, but as far as I can see it does neither. Unless I am missing something?